# Order by within SQL not 100% correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to order by distance but my distances and are output as followed:

```
2m4f
    2m5.5f
    2m5f
    2m6f
    2m7f
    3m
```

As you can see the 2m5.5f comes before 2m.5f

Is there away, by which, I can make it so any value with .5f will come AFTER the "2.5f" like below

```
 2m4f
    2m5f
    2m5.5f
    2m6f
    2m7f
    3m
```

My code for this is:

```
$sqlhorses = "SELECT distance,Place,Runners FROM  `horsesrp`
  WHERE  
 `Horse` = '".$horse."' order by distance";
```

**Notice:** Distance is stored as Varchar(50)

Comment: You should better change the data in your table to be sortable... or make a new collumn with a sortable format...

Comment: Why you don't simply reorder them in your code

Comment: you're sorting **STRINGS**. There's no way for any DB to know that you want a "natural" sort instead. exactly how are those distances, anyways? `2 meters and 5.5 feet`?

Comment: I recommend storing your distance data in a machine readable format, and re-format upon output.

Comment: I think this has been answered already but I was slow typing and don't want to waste my efforts. :)  Assuming you can't change your db, which is what you really should do... `SELECT 
  distance,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(uid, 'm', 1) + 0 AS m,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(uid, 'f', - 1), 'n', 1) + 0 AS f,
  Place,
  Runners 
FROM
  `horsesrp` 
WHERE `Horse` = '".$horse."' 
ORDER BY m, f; ` is what I was slowly typing out on the side here. Add ASC/DESC to taste. (posting as comment so you can credit the faster typers)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments and other answer, the problem is that you are ordering by a string.  In MySQL and with your strings, you can fix this using:

```
order by distance + 0,
         substring_index(distance, 'm', -1) + 0
```

The `+ 0` does a silent conversion in MySQL.  It converts the leading numbers to a number, which is what you want for ordering purposes.

Comment: Could we call "silent conversion" as "Type Casting"?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected result when sorting by a varchar field.  Special characters equate lower than alpha-characters.

You'll need to find a new way to store the data, or simply sort the data in your application code